# Why is this error --> Run Time error 1004 -- popping up?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm not sure why this error is popping up. The VBA code is below. Any help would be appreciated.

The code is trying to update a table then copy a cell value over to another sheet. I recorded the macro, so it should work.

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
'Initialize data
'refresh Tbill table
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets("CurrentTBillYields").Select
    Range("Table_0[[#Headers],[Date]]").Select
    Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    Sheets("Choices").Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
'Copy over the risk free rate
Worksheets("Choices").Range("r_f") = Worksheets("CurrentTBillYields").Range("p4")
End sub
```

Comment: Well, let's start by explaining which line you get the error on. You neglected to mention that.

Comment: "I recorded the macro, so it should work" - not always...

Comment: The error is on Range("Table_0[[#Headers],[Date]]").Select

Comment: By far the most common cause of a run-time Error 1004 is when VBA code refers to a named range that doesn't exist. Perhaps the name is spelled wrong in the code. Or maybe a valid name is used, but it is on a worksheet that isn't active.

Comment: Try taking out the double quotes - I doubt you have a named range called `"Table_0[[#Headers],[Date]]"` - That's a literal string.

Comment: Let me guess... that's the line that you modified after you recorded the macro...

Answer (score 0):

Im assuming that:

1. Error is in the 6th line
2. The table name is named "Table_0"
3. All the ranges in your macro exists

Then replace:

```
Range("Table_0[[#Headers],[Date]]").Select
```

With:

```
Range("Table_0").Select
```

Comment: I made that correction but it still won't work. Any more ideas?

Comment: Can you tell me the exact error? Also try refreshing the query table manually and see if there is an error that pops out. Are you using the Get and Transform feature (Power Query)?

Comment: Run-Time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed. Yes, the table does update manually.

Comment: whenever I record the macro like this it works perfectly (Marco is below), but when I copy and past it into the active button it gives me the errors.

Answer (score 0):

If your connection worked when you recorded it, then it is likely permanently in your workbook.

If that is the case, navigate to `Data-->Existing Connections` and write down the name of the query.

Then, (assuming your button is on the same worksheet you wish to wind up on), you can replace all of your code with something like:

```
ThisWorkbook.Connections("Query - Table 0").Refresh
```